# C regex get index of match

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to use regexes by using regcomp() and regexec() from regex.h, and was wondering if there was any way to get the index of the match if there is one found?

Like if my regex is just "m", and I search "home", I would want 2.

Comment: What do you see populated in the `regmatch_t *pmatch` array you passed to `regexec()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the pmatch and nmatch arguments to regexec(). From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec):

> regexec() is used to match a null-terminated string against the
>   precompiled pattern buffer, preg. nmatch and pmatch are used to
>   provide information regarding the location of any matches. eflags may
>   be the bitwise-or of one or both of REG_NOTBOL and REG_NOTEOL which
>   cause changes in matching behaviour described below.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually looked at the man page, but missed that bit.

Comment: Eh, I tried, bit I don't really get how to use nmatch and pmatch. They seem to be the same regardless of whether I get a match or not, and regardless of where it is. Also, I don't really know what to do with something of type regmatch_t or size_t.